# How to get data from a cross-origin frame in order to make a blogger platform ranking system?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, feed, cross-origin-read-blocking

i have the following question...
Blogger platform hasnt any post ranking system. So, the main solution is to use a third-party ranking system that is not so secure for me....
Therefore, i had an idea to find a way in order to make a blogger platform ranking system, just with blogger parameters.
Something that is similar with ranking system is reactions button widget, that exist in blogger platform.
The problem is that this widget works via iframe, so every post has the following code:

```
<iframe allowtransparency="true" class="reactions-iframe" frameborder="0" name="reactions" scrolling="no" src="https://www.blogger.com/blog-post-reactions.g?options=%5B1star,+2stars,+3stars,+4stars,+5stars%5D&amp;textColor=%23000000#'+posturl+'"></iframe>
```

In this case , the domain is different, it's about a cross-origin frame...

I've used the following code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
        //<![CDATA[
  function getFrameContents(){
   var iFrame =  document.getElementById('frame_2');
   var iFrameBody;
   if ( iFrame.contentDocument ) 
   { // FF
     iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   }
   else if ( iFrame.contentWindow ) 
   { // IE
     iFrameBody = iFrame.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
   }
    alert(iFrameBody.innerHTML);
 }
  //]]>
</script>
<button onclick='getFrameContents()'>Try it</button>
```

and i saw in console log the cross-site frame problem....

Is there any way to get contents from iframe?
I dont want to change iframe data, just i want to get information from this....

Comment: Access to the cross-origin resource is controlled by the server and cannot be overridden by the client.

Comment: with windows.load code? If i said wright?

Comment: even then. regardless of how the content is retrieved.